# Docker command 'docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-run, docker-command

just a quick question as I am learning docker and doing labs:
I have learnt that to run the same command for all/many docker containers that after the command you can use `$(docker -a -q)`
I know `-a` is to call ALL containers in all states, but what does the `-q` mean?

Similarly, in the command:
`docker rm -vf $(docker -a -q)` what does the `-v` mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found the answer to my question already. I'm sharing what I've learner about these letters on a stick below in the hope it will help you, too!

Answer (score 2):

> but what does the -q mean?

the `-` in "-q" denotes a short argument and `q` is short for *quiet*.

> Similarly, in the command: docker rm -vf $(docker -a -q) what does the -v mean?

again, the `-` in "-v" denotes a short argument and `v` is short for *volumes*.

furthermore, the `-` in "-vf" denotes a group of short arguments, each short argument one character and therefore the group being of `v` short for *volumes* and `f` short for *force(=true)*.

---

compare with the output of the `man docker-rm` command:

```
DOCKER(1)                   Docker User Manuals                  DOCKER(1)

NAME
       docker-rm - Remove one or more containers

SYNOPSIS
       docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

DESCRIPTION
       Alias for docker container rm.

OPTIONS
       -f,  --force[=false]       Force the removal of a running container
                                  (uses SIGKILL)

       -h, --help[=false]         help for rm

       -l, --link[=false]         Remove the specified link

       -v, --volumes[=false]      Remove anonymous volumes associated with
                                  the container

SEE ALSO
       docker(1)

Docker Community                 Mar 2021                        DOCKER(1)
```

*(from: DOCKER(1), consult the sources for authorization, and copyright and licensing)*